# program to validate directory name

Tags: c

I just want to write a program which takes a directory name as argument

> - Validate that it is in fact a directory
> - Get a listing of all files in the directory and print it

Comment: Sounds like homework! so you should tag it...

Comment: Which platform are you using ?

Comment: The answer is going to be different for DOS, Linux (Mac, ..., and my refrigerator system, ...), so what Operating System are you using?

Comment: @nos @pmg  I''m using Linux plaform

Comment: @volting Not exactly a homework, newbie to linux platform.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat). It will provide you with the information you want; all you have to do is interpret it.

**Edit:** A brief example.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int is_dir(char *path)
{
    struct stat dir_stats;

    stat(path, &dir_stats);
    if (S_ISDIR(dir_stats.st_mode))
        return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}
```

For the list of files in the directory, use [readdir](http://linux.die.net/man/2/readdir).

Comment: `stat` isn't standard C as far as I know.

Comment: @Jens: True. It's standard *nix though, and vabz didn't specify so I assumed.

Comment: Sorry, But wasn't able to interprete as how can i use Stat to solve my question. can u just elaborate a a bit.  _My question is simple Take any name Validate if it is Directory or not, If yeh print all the file names containing it.__

Comment: @vabz: The link for the text "stat" above will take you to the manual page.

Answer (score 1):

The word directory doesn't even appear in the C standard. This is an OS concept.